# What can I use plugin, for change images

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

[image]

How to do this slider in my situation. Take images collection and change in another place.

Comment: If you jsut want an image Viewer, the please google it. If you have problem with getting code working then please make another post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of plugins available while ping google..

Some samples here...

1. http://www.learningjquery.com/2015/02/best-jquery-image-slider-plugins.
2. http://designscrazed.org/free-responsive-jquery-image-sliders/.

### With out plugin just use sample image slider

Try Following

### JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bretmorris/ulna2/7/

### Html:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="controls">
        <a class="prev" href="javascript:void(0);">Previous Slide</a> |
        <a class="next" href="javascript:void(0);">Next Slide</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/500" width="300" height="500" />
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" width="200" height="400" />
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/400" width="500" height="400" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
/* slideshow initialized w/ js */
.slideshow img { display: none; cursor: pointer; }
```

### Jquery:

```
$('a.prev').click(function() {
    prevSlide($(this).parents('.slideshow').find('.slides'));
});
//clicking image goes to next slide
$('a.next, .slideshow img').click(function() {
    nextSlide($(this).parents('.slideshow').find('.slides'));
});

//initialize show
iniShow();

function iniShow() {
    //show first image
    $('.slideshow').each(function() {
        $(this).find('img:first').fadeIn(500);
    })
}

function prevSlide($slides) {
    $slides.find('img:last').prependTo($slides);
    showSlide($slides);
}

function nextSlide($slides) {
    $slides.find('img:first').appendTo($slides);
    showSlide($slides);
}

function showSlide($slides) {
    //hide (reset) all slides
    $slides.find('img').hide();
    //fade in next slide
    $slides.find('img:first').fadeIn(500);
}
```